# Datatables display a box on hover next to row

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

I have a menu that implements Datatables. You can click `MenuItems` to reveal its `SubItems`:

[image: MenuItem2's sub items on click]

To implement this, I used [Child row guide](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) from Datatables.

So, what I need is instead of clicking a `MenuItem` to reveal its `SubItems` below, I want to be able to just hover on a `MenuItem` and reveal its `SubItems` to the **right** of it, like in the examples below:

[image: MenuItem2's sub items on hover]

One thing to note is that my menu has a height of 100%, so I need to make sure the `SubItems` do not appear below the viewport:

[image]

And instead appear something like this:

[image]

I have tried manually positioning the child row and looking for a way to display the childrow in a div and not a row, but I could not figure this out.

Some code below to get what I have now:

After I initialize my datatable, I run childRowToggle() JS function to achieve the child row on-click:

```
function childRowToggle(tableObj) {
    var tableId = tableObj.table().node().id;

    //if ".details-control" is removed and only "tr" is left, the child row automatically closes when an item is clicked.
    $('#'+tableId + ' tbody').on('click', 'tr.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = tableObj.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {            
            //if another child row already open, close it (not much explanation but it works: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/34367/keep-only-one-child-row-opened-at-a-time)
            if (tableObj.row('.shown').length) {
                $(tableObj.row('.shown').node()).click();
            }

            var childData = returnChildRowElements(row.data());
            // Open this row
            row.child(childData, 'menuItemChildRow').show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    });
}
```

childRowToggle() runs the function below and returns the elements needed. I'm hoping this function can be reused:

```
function returnChildRowElements(d) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    var subItems = ['SubItem1', 'SubItem2', 'SubItem3', 'SubItem4'];

    var tableRows = "";
    pages.forEach(function (subItem) {
        tableRows +=
            '<tr><td>' +
            '<a href="/ControllerName/' + subItem + '/' + d.value["ID"] + '">' + subItem + '</a>' +
            '</td></tr>';
    });

    return '<table class="subItemTable">' + tableRows + '</table>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the on `click` event handler to an on `mouseover`?

```js
$('#'+tableId + ' tbody').on('mouseover', 'tr.details-control', function () {
    // Handle event here
}
```

https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Comment: Thank you for the post, this is a start! The hover doesn't work perfectly but can probably be tinkered with. However, instead of a child row opening up below the menu item, I need it to open to the right of it.